# barrier and its proper verb

Tags: word-choice

could anyone tell me which verb the best collocates with the noun "barrier" (that gate preventing cars,people from passing through it)

would it be

"The guard **released** the barrier"
"The guard lifted/raised the barrier"
"The guard opened the barrier"(it went up, not to the left right etc)

And the other way round.

"The guard closed the barrier"
"The guard got the barrier down"
etc.

Comment: How many examples of say 'opened the barrier' does Google claim?

Comment: I usually think of the general notion of barriers/obstacles as being removed and then replaced , but in this case, as WBT points out, where you seem to be talking about a "gate," opened/lifted and closed/lowered seem best to me.

Comment: It depends on whether the barrier goes up, down, sideways, or somehow diagonal, doesn't it?

Comment: @HotLicks True for lifted/raise and lowered, but open and close might be neutral enough regardless of the direction, although there is debate re draw bridges even with open/close: "There are 2 scheduled openings for the Coleman Bridge this morning." So, yeah, I guess it does depend.

Answer (score 1):

*Opened* is a better fit than *released* and *gate* would generally be a more specific term than *barrier* (if accurate).

*Raised/lowered* could also work if you want to be clear that the mechanism is up/down instead of swinging or sliding, which are more common designs.

Answer (score 0):

If the specific design of the barrier is unknown, you could say:

"The barrier was/will be ***deployed***."

-alternately:

"The barrier was/will be ***withdrawn***."